# Error replacing %n escapes with nth %^{...} string in emacs org capture

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I am trying to write a custom `org-capture` template, but I get an error if I try to use the `%\N` functionality to insert the N-th prompt. The relevant excerpt of my `org-capture-templates` variable is

```
("ao" "Other meeting" entry
 (file+headline "~/org/meeting.org" "Meetings")
 "* %^{meeting date}u Meeting with %^{meeting with}
   :PROPERTIES:
   :MEETWITH: %\\2
   :DESCRIPTION: %\\3
   :END:

   Created on %U
   Description: %^{description}

   %?" :jump-to-captured t :empty-lines 1)
```

When I try to capture, everything goes fine until I `C-c C-c` the note. Then, the new note fails to save due to the following error:

> org-capture: Capture abort: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil

This error only occurs when I try to use the `%\N` functionality, not otherwise. I assume the issue must be somehow related to the relevant section of `org-capture-fill-template`, but I am unable to discern what could be causing this errant behaviour. That section of code is as follows (from `org-capture.el`).

```
    ;; Replace %n escapes with nth %^{...} string.
    (setq strings (nreverse strings))
    (save-excursion
      (while (re-search-forward "%\\\\\\([1-9][0-9]*\\)" nil t)
        (unless (org-capture-escaped-%)
          (replace-match
           (nth (1- (string-to-number (match-string 1))) strings)
           nil t))))
```

**Note:** I have `org-roam` and `org-roam-bibtex` installed. Could this have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the `%^{meeting date}u` does not count as a prompted entry (perhaps because of the `u`? I'm not really sure). So it thinks there are only *two* prompted entries: `%^{meeting with}` and `%^{description}` so the template should look like this:

```el
("ao" "Other meeting" entry
 (file+headline "~/org/meeting.org" "Meetings")
 "* %^{meeting date}u Meeting with %^{meeting with}
   :PROPERTIES:
   :MEETWITH: %\\1
   :DESCRIPTION: %\\2
   :END:

   Created on %U
   Description: %^{description}

   %?" :jump-to-captured t :empty-lines 1)
```

EDIT: I looked at the code (in [org-capture.el:org-capture-fill-template](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/lisp/org-capture.el#L1705)) more carefully. The only time when prompted entries are saved for later use with `%\N` constructs is when they are *not* decorated with a key (`CgGLptTuUptTuU`).
So the diagnosis above is correct: the `u` causes the entry not to be remembered for further use with `%\N`.

This seems deliberate so it's probably not a bug, but a design decision. In particular, the doc string for `org-capture-templates` says:

> %\1 ... %\N Insert the text entered at the nth %^{prompt}, where N
> is a number, starting from 1.

Note that it does not mention the `%^{prompt}<key>` form at all.